# Program To print specific path of folder into its next sub folder in java

Tags: java

Create below file and folder on your desktop except that do not assume the depth of the structure is fixed meaning there could be more folders such as T5, T6 etc.

Write a function to display path of all files in the folder relative to the first file encountered in that folder. Write each path on separate line and also include name of the first file.

E.g. the function should display below output for the above file/folder structure:

T1.indd

Links/Tree.png

Links/Images/T1.jpg

Docs/T1.docx

Comment: Any code to this or are we supposed to do your homework? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can recommend to you is study the `File` class in Java. This class contains all the methods you need for read,list the content of a folder and more utils methods.

Here is the link, I hope that this can help you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

If you want more help, please show your code.